# Why is my cloud run deploy hanging at the "Deploying..." step?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

Up until today, my deploy process has worked fine. Today when I go to deploy a new revision, I get stuck at the `Deploying...` text with a spinning indicator, and it says `One or more of the referenced revisions does not yet exist or is deleted`. I've tried a number of different images and flags -- all the same.

Comment: Can  you share more detail? How do you deploy? Where? which image? Do you have logs?

Answer (score 1):

See [Viewing the list of revisions for a service](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/managing/revisions#viewing_the_list_of_revisions_for_a_service), in order to undo whatever you may have done.

Probably you have the wrong project selected, if it does not know any of the revisions.

Comment: Wish that were the case, but actually can see the revision in the right project.  The `gcloud deploy` command just seems to hang, and I can't seem to direct any traffic to the new revisions from the console web interface, even.

Comment: Same here. It looks like a bug honestly

Answer (score 0):

I know I provided scant information, but just to follow up with an answer:  it looks like the issue was that I was deploying a revision, and then immediately trying to tag it using `gcloud alpha run services update-traffic <service_name> --set-tags` which looks to have caused some sort of race, where it complained that the revision was not yet deployed, and would hang indefinitely.  Moving the `set-tag` into the `gcloud alpha run deploy` seemed to fix it.

Comment: can you please share the yaml file that allowed you to tag a revision after its creation

Comment: I tend to use `gcloud` on the command line (usually in the context of bash scripts), if not Pulumi (python infrastructure tool), to deploy things, so apologies: no yaml file to share.